# Sorting an array to avoid neighboring items having duplicate attributes

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting, object, actionscript

I have an array of objects. Each object has a color attribute which could be "red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange" or "purple". There are 20-30 objects in the array so colors repeat. My goal is to sort the array so that no colors are next to each other. Distribution of colors is not exactly even but close.

This is what I have so far. It checks the next and previous object for a color match and if it finds a match it moves it to the end of the array.

```
private function sortColors():void
{
    var getNext:uint;
    var getPrev:uint;
    var maxCount:uint = colorArray.length;
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < maxCount; i++) {
        var cur:ValueObject = colorArray[i];
        (i == maxCount-1) ? getNext = 0 : getNext = i+1;
        (i == 0) ? getPrev = maxCount-1 : getPrev = i-1;
        var next:ValueObject = colorArray[getNext];
        var prev:ValueObject = colorArray[getPrev];
        if (cur.color == next.color) {
            var move:ValueObject = colorArray[getNext];
            colorArray.splice(getNext, 1);
            colorArray.push(move);
        }
        if (cur.color == prev.color) {
            var move:ValueObject = colorArray[getPrev];
            colorArray.splice(getPrev, 1);
            colorArray.push(move);
        }
    }
}
```

This works OK but if there is more of a certain color they end up repeating at the end. I could add something to the end to throw those back into the mix but I feel like there must be a better way. Someone enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var colorObjects:Array = [/* list of objects with colors - populated below*/];
var jumbled:Array = [];

var lastColor:String = "";
function getDifferentTile():void
{
    if(lastColor.length == 0)
    {
        jumbled.push(colorObjects.pop());
        lastColor = jumbled[0].mycolor;
    }
    else
    {
        var i:Object;
        for each(i in colorObjects)
        {
            var repeat:uint = 0;
            if(i.mycolor != lastColor)
            {
                jumbled.push(i);
                lastColor = i.mycolor;

                colorObjects.splice(colorObjects.indexOf(i), 1);

                return;
            } else {
               repeat++;
            }
            if (repeat > 0 && repeat == colorObjects.length) {
               jumbled.push(i);
               colorObjects.splice(colorObjects.indexOf(i), 1);
               return;
            }
        }
    }
}

// list of random colors
var colors:Array = ["0x000000","0x444444","0xFFFFFF","0xFF00FF"];

// prepare random array for test
var i:uint = 0;
for(i; i<100; i++)
{
    var obj:Object =
    {
        mycolor: colors[uint(Math.random()*colors.length)]
    };

    colorObjects.push(obj);
}


// fill the jumble array until the original listing is empty
while(colorObjects.length > 0)
{
    getDifferentTile();
}


// output jumbled
var j:Object;
for each(j in jumbled)
{
    trace(j.mycolor);
}
```

Comment: @knuckfubuck Indeed it seems this is the opposite of what you want.. Sorry, just got up. One moment.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look again. This is more concise than my original code but it has an issue. The "while" can get stuck in an infinite loop if the "for each" can't find a different color. This can happen if let's say the array is left with 4 items of the same color near the end of the loop. I'm editing your code to address that.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help anyways.