# Sorting an array so that 3 types of objects are evenly distributed throughout the array?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

iSo let's say I have three different arrays of objects, and I want to combine them into one sorted array. I want the order to be such that the items from each array are evenly distributed throughout the sorted array.

If there were 3 xItems, 3 yItems, and 3 zItems, the sorted array would have this order: 
x, y, z, x, y, z, x, y, z

HOWEVER, even if the arrays are differing lengths, I still need to make them alternate as much as possible. If there were 6 xItems, 4 yItems, and 2 zItems, the sorted array should have this order: 
x, y, x, y, x, z, x, y, x, y, x, z

The closest answer I could find was [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738282/sorting-an-array-to-avoid-neighboring-items-having-duplicate-attributes), where they unfortunately never found an answer :(

I'm working an Actionscript 3. Thank you to anyone who can steer me in the right direction!

Comment: What you describe is not sorting.

Comment: What would be the correct term to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break this problem into smaller problems. My attempt on this would be something like:

**Problem 1:** How to merge 2 collections, so that the elements are evenly distributed.

Collection A: X X X X X X

Collection B: Y Y

Result: X X X Y X X X Y

**Problem 2:** How to merge the 3 collections?

I would proceed in the following way:

*Step 1:* Sort the 3 collection by their length.

*Step 2:* Merge the shortest 2 collections into one collection with the solution from **Problem 1.**

*Step 3:* Merge the third collection with the result from *Step 2* again with the same algorithm from **Problem 1.**

So, basically  now you have to solve only **Problem 1.**

Comment: This is a good way to look at it. I will leave another comment with my code if I can get it figured out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Problem 1 is not that difficult to figure out, but nevertheless I thought putting it in my answer would destroy the fun for you.